# Radio button checked by default when using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, html, radio-button

I have been wanting to have a radio button checked out of a list of radio buttons that I present in the screen using ng-repeat, but my code does not work.  This is what I am doing:

```
<div class="clubRole" data-ng-if="club.checked">
    <div data-ng-repeat="role in securityGroups.slice(0,1)">
        <input type="radio" class="clubRole" data-ng-model="club.role" data-ng-value="role.securityGroupCode" checked="checked"> {{role.description}}
    </div>
    <div data-ng-repeat="role in securityGroups.slice(1,securityGroups.length+1)">
        <input type="radio" class="clubRole" data-ng-model="club.role" data-ng-value="role.securityGroupCode"> {{role.description}}
    </div>      
</div>
```

The intention of the code is to get the first radio button checked, and the others unchecked. That code has a problem: it does not work. But at least it gives the idea of what I am trying to do: I want one of the radio buttons checked by default, no matter which one it is.

Comment: you should use `data-ng-model="$parent.club.role"` because you used `ng-if`

Comment: @pankajparkar, I believe it's `ng-repeat` that creates its own scope, not ng-if

Comment: @Victor `ng-if` also creates a new scope, you need to look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Radio button will be check if the value of the input attribute is equal to the value of modal applied on the radio button.

```
 <div ng-repeat="val in ['a','b','c']">
     <input
            type="radio"
            name="val"
            data-ng-model="role" 
            data-ng-value="val"
            ng-init="$index==0?(role=val):''"
      />
     {{val}}
 </div>
```

Checked="checked" will not work in angular context. You can either set the value of radio button explicitly in controller or you can manage it in the view itself as i did in the above example.But the modal should be equate according to the value attribute on the inmput element.

For example if modal is x on three radio button's and each radio button have different value like a,b and c. then x must be equal to any of the value to be checked.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zihMeNkV8gqRLMiIfp7a?p=preview)

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to worry about checked.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="mainController">
    <label ng-repeat="option in options">
        <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.selected" ng-value="option"/>{{option}}
    </label>
</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var appModule = angular.module('app', []);

appModule.controller('mainController', function($scope) {

$scope.selected = 'red';
$scope.options = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green'];

});
```

Working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/qnw8ogrk/1/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `checked="checked"`, I think angular will take care of it itself if you set the model to one of the values.  Something like:

```
club.role = securityGroups.slice(0,1)[0].securityGroupCode;
```

Also, the scope may trip you up here, the model may have to be `$parent.club.role`

Answer (score 1):

if you use a primitive type in list, the answer of bm1729 is correct, but if you use objects in the list, then look this example: https://jsfiddle.net/9chd58mk/2/

the first part is bad, because the selected object is look like same with a list item, but it doesn't same by reference. the == operator is false in this case

```
$scope.selected = {c:'red'};
$scope.options = [{c:'red'}, {c:'blue'}, {c:'yellow'}, {c:'green'}];
```

but the second and third examples are use the list item reference, and the radio button checked. the == operator is true in this case

```
$scope.options3 = [{c:'red'}, {c:'blue'}, {c:'yellow'}, {c:'green'}];
$scope.selected3 = $scope.options3[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <md-radio-group ng-model="data.group3">
                                                    <md-radio-button value="{{o._id}}" class="md-primary" ng-repeat="o in lstDataRecord" ng-click="updTemplateId(o._id)">
                                                        <div flex-gt-sm="50" style="height: 150px; width: 250px;">
                                                            <img src="{{PageInfo_PATH}}{{o.imgUrl}}" />
                                                            {{o.displayName}}
                                                        </div>
                                                    </md-radio-button>
                                                    <md-radio-button value="active" class="md-primary" [checked]='true'> </md-radio-button>
                                                </md-radio-group>
```

Comment: Your answer is only code. Please improve it with some explanations.