# Form radio buttons referencing old memory when ng-model is changed - breaks ng-check

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular 1.*

I have:

```
  <div class="filter-column">
    <div class="filter-title">Market</div>
    <div class="bottom-line"></div>
    <div class="overflow-container">
        <input type="radio" value="all" name="marketRadio" 
          ng-checked="true" class="resetAll" ng-model="filter.markets" 
          ng-change="radioMap('market')" checked>All
      <div ng-repeat="choice in markets| orderBy: 'name'">
        <input type="radio" value="{{choice.name}}" name="marketRadio"
          ng-change="radioMap('market')" ng-model="filter.markets" >
        {{choice.description}}
      </div>
    </div>
```

In the controller I have:

```
  var ppvFilter = {
    regions: [],
    markets: [],
    dealers: []
  };



  $scope.$watchCollection(function() {
    return ppvFilter;
  },
    function(newValue) {
      $scope.regions = newValue.regions;
      $scope.markets = newValue.markets;
      $scope.dealers = newValue.dealers;
  });
```

When I refresh the radio button list programaticly(not page refresh) with `ppvFilter.markets.length = 0; ppvFilter.markets = ppvFilter.markets.concat(['a', 'b', 'c'])`, the list of radio button choices updates as it should in the gui. However, `ng-checked="true"` no longer works for `all` and it is unchecked after the list updates.

I suspect it is because the angular form is referencing old memory even though it is showing the new list of radio buttons.

Answer (score 1):

From the angular [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) on ngChecked: **Note that this directive should not be used together with ngModel, as this can lead to unexpected behavior.**

Comment: still same behavior even without ng-model and ng-change.

Comment: Any way you could put it in a plunker or fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.... the default item HAS to be in the ng-repeat. `ng-check` is not much use in real life.

Reference:

[Radio button checked by default when using ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29539549/radio-button-checked-by-default-when-using-ng-repeat)